# Geometric Brownian Motion with non-negative random increments

Tags: sde

I am attempting to model a cumulative time-series of a positive integer variable across independent entities. The cumulative series appears to follow a process of Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) based on lognormal distributions seen cross-sectionally at each time point.

The standard treatments and estimation methods for GBM drift ($m$) and diffusion ($s$) coefficients are based upon a specification where the random variation at each time point comes from a Wiener process $W(t)$ with normally distributed increments of zero mean:

$$dX(t) = m X(t) dt + s X(t) dW(t)$$

In my problem, this cannot apply since X(t) is a cumulative sum of positive numbers. Random increments can be positive or zero only, and the mean will be non-zero and positive. A normal distribution truncated below 0 appears to be appropriate.

Can anyone point me to a treatment and estimation approach for this type of problem? I believe the standard estimation methods do not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

I think the notion of a [Lévy process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process) fits for your problem. Lévy processes with only positive increments are called [Lévy subordinators](http://galton.uchicago.edu/~lalley/Courses/385/LevyProcesses.pdf). Poisson processes as lehalle proposes are a subclass of these. Compound Poisson processes are an easy generalization of Poisson processes, they have only positive increments if you assume that the "2nd" distribtion (jump size) is non-negative. I can provide details but you find good sources online too.
EDIT: I just read positive integer. Then only compound poisson with integer valued jumps size distribution works ... (e.g. Negative Binomial).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you do not need a Poisson Process (see for instance [a course about them](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap02.pdf))?

Poisson processes are commonly used to model the sum of arrival times. They are very useful to model high frequency data (arrivale rates of buy / sell orders). You can couple several Poisson processes using Hawkes processes (see [Modeling microstructure noise with mutually exciting point processes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3422)).